# SQLite 'long' integers are returned truncated/incorrect by SQL select query — how can the correct values be retrieved? (SQLite ODBC driver, VBA/ADODB)

Tags: sql, vba, sqlite, adodb, anki

In Excel VBA with the [SQLite ODBC Driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/), my simple SELECT query run against a single table retrieves 'long' integers (10 or more decimal places) incorrectly. How can these values be retrieved correctly, without truncation or whatever garbling is going on?

(**PLEASE NOTE:** the database structure/field definitions can't be modified — the database belongs to an open source application, **Anki**, and changing the structure would break the software.)

The particular table I'm querying contains (at least) several fields that can contain longer integer values (10 or more decimal places). The primary key ("id") contains Unix timestamp (datetime) values, with milliseconds, so the integer in the primary key field always occupies 13 decimal places.

Here is the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE "notes" (
    "id"    integer,
    "guid"  text NOT NULL,
    "mid"   integer NOT NULL,
    "mod"   integer NOT NULL,
    "usn"   integer NOT NULL,
    "tags"  text NOT NULL,
    "flds"  text NOT NULL,
    "sfld"  integer NOT NULL,
    "csum"  integer NOT NULL,
    "flags" integer NOT NULL,
    "data"  text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY("id")
);
```

One of my records has the value 1640497387755 in the id field. If I run this query:

```
SELECT id AS primarykey, flds FROM notes WHERE id = 1640497387755
```

the results contain 2147483647 in the `primarykey` field (a 1-record ADO recordset)—not 1640497387755. The `flds` field in the recordset has the correct (textual) data, however.

I have verified that the field contains the correct/expected Unix timestamp values by browsing the database with a separate tool ([DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org)). Note further that I'm able to select the correct record(s) using WHERE clauses based on the actual `id` field value(s) in the database, as in the `SELECT` statement above.

Casting the field to BigInt and BigInteger hasn't affected the results—for example, I get exactly the same results with:

```
SELECT CAST(id as biginteger) AS primarykey, flds FROM notes
```

Neither has setting the BigInt parameter for the ADODB connection, as shown in my code below (see
[documentation for the SQL ODBC Driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/html/index.html), under the heading "Connect string parameters for DSN-less connects").

Here is a minimal example of working VBA code demonstrating the problem in all its frustrating fullness:

```vb
Sub ADOQueryAnki()
        
    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim varRecords() As Variant
    Dim strDBasePath As String
    Dim strSQLSelect As String
    
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    strDBasePath = "I:\Anki\Test\collection.anki2;" 
    ' collection.anki2 is a standard SQLite database
    ' --though the filename has a non-standard extension
    strSQLSelect = "SELECT id as primarykey, flds FROM notes"
    
    ' OPEN CONNECTION
    conn.Open "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=" & strDBasePath & ";BigInt = true"
    conn.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    
    rst.Open strSQLSelect, conn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic ' have tried multiple options
    
    Debug.Print rst!primarykey
    
End Sub
```

In the run I just did, the `Debug.Print` statement outputs 2147483647, where the actual value of the corresponding field in the database is 1324302169120.

Note that the `ActualSize` and `DefinedSize` properties for the field in the recordset are both shown in the VBA debugger as "4," meaning (I think) 4 bytes, whereas SQLite uses 8 bytes to store these values in the database.

[image]

Comment: IIRC this is a legacy restriction in VBA/ADODB or their combination.  Best solutions might be to use either decimal, double-precision floating point and/or strings.  (Hmm, actually this might be a debugger limitation...)

Comment: .. so maybe try casting the SQLlite `id` to text or real.

Comment: Curious, in connection string try `;BigInt=True;` or `;BigInt=1;`. And try removing `CursorLocation` attribute. The ado type returns `adInteger` but ideally should return `adoBigInt`

Comment: I have tried both 'True' (and 'true') and 1 for BigInt. Just now removed CursorLocation attribute, no change in results.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: Thanks, and yes, casting to text "works" though it requires re-conversion of the string values back to numbers in code. (I haven't tried casting to real but assume it would work as well.) Having to re-convert is suboptimal for various reasons, especially in that the possibility for error increases with increasing code complexity. If that's the best option, so be it. I'll wait awhile to see if anyone else knows what's wrong with my approach, if the problem isn't inherent in the tools I'm using.

Comment: How about `;BigInt=yes`? I see from your profile, you use Python. If installed for Windows, can you check with pyodbc? Try: `import pyodbc; conn = pyodbc.connect(<connection string with BigInt>); cur = conn.cursor(); cur.execute(<SQL query>); print(cur.fetchone()[0]); cur.close(); conn.close()`? Need to isolate if this is an ADO or ODBC driver issue.

Comment: @Parfait: Turns out that it was the white space in the BigInt parameter part of the connection string. Although whitespace is ignored in OLEDB connection strings (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms722656(v=vs.85)#setting-values-that-use-spaces) I guess it isn't ignored in ODBC, or at least in this ODBC flavor. 'BigInt=true' works, whereas 'BigInt = true' fails silently. Sheesh. Good suggestion on using Python to isolate the issue but re-reading your first comment led to the a direct solution. Happy New Year, everyone.

Comment: Very odd because the same link mentions preceding and trailing spaces are ignored but not within! See second example in section. So `BigInt = true` should be synonymous to `BigInt=true`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, essentially the issue derives from *how* to include the `BigInt` parameter in connection string. While [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms722656(v=vs.85)) appears to differ from implementation, key/value pairs should avoid whitespaces:

```vb
DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=" & strDBasePath & ";BigInt=true"
```

Lessons learned in debugging special attributes to ODBC connection strings:

- Avoid preceding and trailing whitespaces and use single quotes for special string attributes;
- For boolean attributes, check for case sensitivity (`true` vs `True`), integer (0, 1) synonyms, string (yes/no) synonyms;
- For ending attributes, check for punctuation such as ending semicolon;
- Run vanilla versions of connections and recordsets using default params without special configurations such as for `CursorLocation`, `CursorType`, and `LockType`;
- Debug in other languages (i.e., Python, PowerShell) that support ODBC as control check to isolate environment or interface issues;
- Carefully read documentation of specific ODBC driver or library/module and API like ADO.